# How to wait before res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sweetalert

I have a button in my HTML file which calls a post route when it's clicked and submits a form. The button click also calls a function in my other javascript file that activates a 'sweetalert' alert box.

However, the problem that I have now is that the user does not get enough time to read the alert before the post request executes `res.redirect("/")`.

I was hoping for any one of the following solutions:

1) Call the alert after the page is redirected (I read somewhere that you cannot control the next page with node.js so this may not be possible).

2) Wait a few seconds before `res.redirect("/")` is called.

3) Any other appropriate solution.

HTML file that contains the button:

```
<button formaction="/removetask" type="submit" id="top" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="success()"> Complete </button>
```

client-side javascript file:

```
function success(){
  ...
  swal("Congratulations!", "Goal successfully completed", "success")

}
```

node.js file:

```
app.post("/removetask", async function(req, res) {
  ...
  res.redirect("/");  
});
```

link to 'sweetalert' in HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

I notice that using the regular HTML `alert()` stops everything and prevents redirection until the user has closed the alert. Is it possible to change the 'sweetalert` alert to behave like this?

Comment: maybe instead of redirecting when the user clicks the button, you can simply just perform the task removal operation. Then, once the user clicks "ok" on the swal popup, you can then redirect them

Comment: @Nick Parsons what if the user doesn't click the 'ok' and instead click outside the alert box which would also close the alert. I redirect to the root page because I want the page to refresh and update the data.

Comment: I think sweetalert allows you to run events on clicking of the button or on closing the popup by clicking the outside of it. You could also disable the close on outside click as well if you're willing to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit.
Now by clicking form is not submiting.

Jest after you click on the success button the form will be submitted.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="top" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="success()"> Complete </button>
```

JS:

```
function success(){
  swal({
  title: "Congratulations!",
  text: "Goal successfully completed",
  type: "success",
  }).then(function(){ 
      document.getElementById('form').submit();
  });
}
```

https://code.sololearn.com/WGoSH0qXkP9I/#html

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but unfortunately it still doesn't act like the standard Javascript alert in the sense that it does not wait for the user to close the alert before nodejs redirects the page.

Comment: Sorry! I was forgotten to add 'type="button"'.

I update the code in the link.

For me it works jest fine.
I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try other ways to display alarms.

First, you don't need to redirect to original page.

```
app.post("/removetask", async function(req, res) {
  ...
  res.render('alarm page') 
});
```

And on the alarm page, the javascript file will set the time to wait for a moment.

alarmpagejs.js follow

```
  setTimeout(() => {
     window.location = "/";
  }, 5000)
```

Then the result will be this logic:

1. button click
2. rendering alarm page
3. redirecting to '/' by alarm page.js

You can wait for an arbitrary amount of milliseconds

Comment: Excuse my lack of nodejs knowledge, but what does res.render('alarm page') actually do? Do I need to create a new html file called alarmpage.html?

Comment: render function works render the html on the url. For instance, if you call res.render('hello.html') in '/hi' , there will be rendered hello.html contents at /hi

Comment: I used `app.set("view engine", "ejs");` before in my code because I had a .ejs file, so when I do `res.render('alarmpage')`, I ge the error: `Error: Failed to lookup view "alarmpage" in views directory`.How do i go about this?

Comment: Of course there are error. That is just a example. You need to create other alarm view file. Like alarm.ejs. and you can write like ``` res.render('alarm.ejs', {message:"blabla"}) ``` we need to code other ejs file.